# Como enviar uma imagem para o backend e fazer upload nodejs

Tags: node.js, express.js

Tenho uma aplicação em react que envia uma imagem para o backend em node o problema é que não consigo pegar o arquivo no express. Vi que tem como usar o multer so que não sei como passar o arquivo para a chamada do imgur.
basicamente preciso enviar o arquivo do fron-end pro backend e passar esse arquivo pra api do imgur. mão não achei nenhuma forma de recuperar essa imagem no backend.

Pra explicar melhor, eu consigo salvar os arquivos localmente com o multer, o problema é que eu preciso do backend enviar essa imagem para outra api, que só aceita aquivos e não base64. Meu problema é ai, como eu posso passar esse pegar esse arquivo no backend.

No front eu uso o axios e FormData, mais no back não sei como pegar esse arquivo, para passar a outra api.

Comment: Entao como falei na resposta, basta indicar o caminho relativo do ficheiro e passar pelo imgur https://www.npmjs.com/package/imgur#uploading-files-globbing-supported talvez a parte de envio pro imgur esteja mais clara aqui editei a minha resposta se achares que resolveu fico grato pela validacao

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entao , pra começar vais precisar de usar uma pasta estática podes fazer isto com o express, se não tiveres o modulo ainda usa isto

```
npm init -y
npm i -S express@4.15.4
```

Declarar a pasta estatica

```
const express = require('express')
    , app = express();

app.use(express.static('caminho_da_pasta'));
app.listen(numero_da_porta, () => console.log('App na porta numero_da_porta'));
```

Agora pra usar o multer:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: 'pasta_de_rececao/' });

//upload com um POST

app.post('caminho_dentro_da_pasta_estatica', upload.single('nome_da_tag'), 
    (req, res) => res.send('Sucesso'));
```

O upload.single('nome_da_tag') indica que estamos interessado no dado enviado com o name file, o mesmo name utilizado pelo

```
<input type="file" name="nome_da_tag">
```

Se tiver sucesso o teu arquivo vai se encontrar dentro da pasta indicada só que o nome do ficheiro será diferente do nome original pra ter o nome original com a extensão e necessário indicar um Storage com o multer tambem

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {

        cb(null, 'pasta_de_rececao/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {

        cb(null, `${file.fieldname} + '-' +${path.extname(file.originalname)`})
    }
});



//e em vez de passar a pasta_de_rececao como argumento , passamos a storage
const upload = multer({ storage });
```

basta depois pegar no caminho da image + o nome da imagem e enviar com o modulo do imgur

```
var imgur = require('imgur');
imgur.setAPIUrl('https://api.imgur.com/');

imgur.uploadFile('/caminho/da/imagem.png')
.then(function (json) {
    console.log(json.data.link);
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
});
```

fonte:[imgur](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imgur#uploading-files-globbing-supported)
Espero que ajude

Comment: eu atualizei a pergunta, pra ficar mais clara a minha duvida.

Comment: Editei agora a resposta @LukasTakahashi pra ser mais pormenorizada

Comment: Brigado! esse método é funcional, mais me fica a duvida se eu não quiser ter o arquivo no meu servidor, toda vez que o Usuário fazer o upload eu tenho que salvar a imagem, mandar pra api e apagar a imagem. Tem um modo em que não seja preciso salvar a imagem no meu servidor?

Comment: Como falaste mais acima ,podes codificar-la em base64 e enviar diretamente para o github

Answer (score 2):

Como você está utilizando React, imagino que fará uma requisição Ajax para passar a imagem para a API.
Para fazer isto em JavaScript utilize `FormData` como o trecho abaixo ilustra:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="meuForm">
    <input type="file" id="inputImg" />
    <input type="submit" value="Postar" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('meuForm').onsubmit = function() {
    const input = document.getElementById('inputImg');
    const file = input.files[0];

    const formData = new FormData();    
    formData.append('anexo', file);
    formData.append('nome', 'teste');
    // TODO chamada AJAX passando o FormData
};
```

Já no backend é necessário instalar o `multer` ou outra lib que efetue o parse de formulários `multipart/form-data`.
Abaixo há um exemplo que utilizo em um projeto pessoal. Retirei alguns trechos que não são necessários para sua solução:

```
exports.post = async (req, res) => {
    var multer = require('multer');

    var upload = null;
    try {
        var path = require('path');
        var storage = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: function (req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, process.env.DIRETORIOUPLOAD);
            },
            filename: function (req, file, cb) {
                fileExtension = file.originalname.split('.')[1];
                cb(null, require('crypto')
                    .randomBytes(64).toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname));
            }
        });

        upload = multer({ storage: storage }).fields([
            { name: 'anexo', maxCount: 1 }
        ]);
    } catch (ex) {
    // (...)
    }

    upload(req, res, async err => {
        if (err) {
            // (...)
        }

        // Quando o código chegar aqui é porque seu arquivo já 
        // foi salvo no disco. Agora você pode continuar com seu processamento
        // lendo os demais campos postados
        // Demais campos postados:
        const nome = req.body.nome; // Valor 'teste' neste exemplo

        // (...)

        res.json({ ok: 1 });
    });
}
```

Comment: eu atualizei a pergunta, pra ficar mais clara a minha duvida

Comment: @LukasTakahashi agora ficou mais claro! Seria possível detalhar um pouco melhor como essa API está esperando receber a imagem? De antemão talvez este link te ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994269/nodejs-send-binary-data-with-request

Comment: Brigado por responder, vou dar uma olhada no link e testar.